# Number auto increase with other while function (PHP)

Tags: php, while-loop

I want the queqe id auto increase start from 1

I have an mysql table call `t1`

mysql table `t1` Data as below:

```
+----------+------------------+-------------+
| ID       | Name             | Status      |
+----------+------------------+-------------+
| 1        | ABBCCC           | 1           |
| 2        | BASDASD          | 1           |
| 3        | ABBCCC           | 1           |
| 4        | ABBCCC           | 2           |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

I loop data in php like this:

```
$quserCA = DB::query("SELECT * FROM ".DB::table('jnbook_book')." WHERE Name = 'ABBCCC' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20");
$nqCA = mysql_num_rows($quserCA);
while($ruserCA = DB::fetch($quserCA)){
    $CAlist[] = $ruserCA;
}
$x = 1;
while($x <= $nqCA) {
    //echo "The number is: $x <br>";
    $x++;
}
```

I loop this in my htm like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Queqe ID</td><td>ID</td><td>Status</td>
  </tr>
  <!--{loop $CAlist $value}-->
  <tr>
    <td>{$x}</td><td>{$value[id]}</td><td>{$value[status]}</td>
  </tr>
  <!--{/loop}-->
</table>
```

But after that my table output as below show

```
+---------------+-------------------+----------------+
| Queqe ID      | ID                | Status         |
+---------------+-------------------+----------------+
| 1             | 1                 | 1              |
| 1             | 3                 | 1              |
| 1             | 4                 | 2              |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Actually what I want the table output as below

(I want the queqe id auto increase start from 1):

```
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Queqe ID | ID              | Status          |
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 1        | 1               | 1               |
| 2        | 3               | 1               |
| 3        | 4               | 2               |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Thank you.

Comment: why not do `{$x++}` in your html and remove your `while()` loop entirely?

Comment: i have try, then the queqe id show {1++} for all row..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be done something like:

```
$x = 1;
while($ruserCA = DB::fetch($quserCA)){
    // add a field, say `x` with number of a record:
    $ruserCA['x'] = $x++;

    $CAlist[] = $ruserCA;
}
```

In a template:

```
<td>{$value[x]}</td><td>{$value[id]}</td><td>{$value[status]}</td>
```